# how to run a function on every task of a namespace with rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I want to run a simple function, enter_to_continue on every rake task in a namespace.
currently I add that function at the end of every single task

however, it seems redundant, is there any way to run this function, enter_to_continue, to run at the end of every task of namespace 'mytest' automatically, by doing some meta programming?

```
namespace :mytest do
  task :foo do
    system "date"
    enter_to_continue
  end

  task :bar do 
    system "ls"
    enter_to_continue
  end

  # ...
  # Let's say 10 more tasks ends with enter_to_continue comes after 
  # ...
end

def enter_to_continue
  STDIN.gets.chomp
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Rake::Task#enhance:

```
require 'rake'

ns = namespace :mytest do

  task :foo do |t|
    puts "You called task #{t}"
  end

  task :bar do |t|
    puts "You called task #{t}"
  end

  # ...
  # Let's say 10 more tasks ends with enter_to_continue comes after 
  # ...
end

#
#Add actions to each task (e.g. enter_to_continue)
#
ns.tasks.each{|tsk|
  tsk.enhance { puts "\treached method #{__method__}" }
}

#Test the result
task :default => "mytest:foo"
task :default => "mytest:bar"
if $0 == __FILE__
  Rake.application[:default].invoke
end
```

Edit:
You may enhance the tasks also inside the definition block:

```
namespace :mytest do |ns|
  # 
  #...Task definitions...
  #
  ns.tasks.each{|tsk|
    tsk.enhance { puts "\treached method #{__method__}" }
  }
end
```